# How to read Content Editor Web Part Id from the javascript in it?

Tags: javascript, content-editor-web-part

I have added a content editor web part in a SharePoint web part page. I have some java script code  logic which renders some HTML and I have added that script to content editor web part Content Link.

Is it possible to read the current content editor web part Id or any unique property of the current content editor web part from the script being linked in Content Link?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the file linked using Content Link to show WebPart ID. Requires jQuery.

```
<div id="mySpan"></div>
<script>
    $("#mySpan").closest("div[WebPartID]").attr("WebPartID")
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

*NOT TESTED - pulled it from old code*

Without jQuery and not requiring a 'marker' DIV to know where your code is

Since you can add events to an IMG tag

```
<span>
  <img onerror="
                var el=this;
                while (!(el.getAttribute(dataAttr) || el===document.body))el=el.parentNode;
                var id=el.getAttribute(dataAttr);
                this.parentNode.innerHTML=id;
    ">
</span>
```

Should result in:

```
<span>
  3766612-68c3-46cf-bb31-f0725c7f71f
</span>
```